# Using the BitBucket as a private repository in java,Spring Boot

Tags: maven, repository, bitbucket, private

I have created the repository according to this link https://dzone.com/articles/using-github-as-maven-repository
But Now When I am Accessing this in my Projects, It is not able to download the dependencies and update it.
I have added the Jars in the BitBucket Repository.

I have tried 
1. Changing the BitBucket URL
2.

Expected - It should automatically Download the Jar
Actual - It is not

Comment: Have you  set  username and email in git

Comment: Yes, I have Given the Username and password in settings.xml present in .m2 folder

Comment: I made new user in bitbucket

Comment: set  username and email in git: terminal>>

git config --global user.name "name"
git config --global user.email email@email.com